# Setting localstorage cookie service that contains spaces inbetween words

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I can set the cookie fine,how ever if the cookie name that I am setting is "Cookie code 1" it gets saved as 
`"cookie%20code%201"`. How do I solve this issue with the spaces in between words?

```
self.cookie=function(){
    localStorageService.cookie.set("CookieId",decodeURIComponent(self.Id), 100000);

  }
```

Comment: you need to use `decodeURIComponent(self.Id)` while setting value

Comment: i have edited my code and tried the following however it doesnt make any change it still gets stored with %20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) for $cookieStore says the following:

> Provides a key-value (string-object) storage, that is backed by session cookies. Objects put or retrieved from this storage are automatically serialized or deserialized by angular's toJson/fromJson.

Means, serialize and unserialize ([urlEncoded](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp)) happens automatically. So i promise you are using this plugin atm https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage#cookieget, which also serialize/unserialize. Just use `localStorageService.cookie.get(key);` to check the callback.

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  //...
  function setAndGetItem(key) {
    localStorageService.cookie.set(), "Its a cookie"); // persisted as "Its%20a%20cookie"
    console.log(localStorageService.cookie.get(key)); // returns "Its a cookie"
  }
  //...
});
```